# Swift bind AnyObserver to Observable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rx-swift

So, for example I have this observer in `var myObserver: AnyObserver<Bool>`
Can I somehow subscribe to it like for an `observable`, so I would be able to do some operations with it like `.subscribe(onNext:)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Observer` is what you actually pass to `subscribe(...)`

In this example, you could do

```
var myObserver: AnyObserver<Bool> = //...

myObservable
  .subscribe(myObserver)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The syntax `subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:)` is just syntactic sugar to not have to actually create an `Observer` object every time.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example? For instance, how would you initialize `myObserver` in the above example? `var myObserver: AnyObserver<Bool> = true` throws a compiler error. Also how would you read the `Bool` value in the `myObservable` subscription? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Observable` is a read-only entity. You can only subscribe to "Read" things off of it and manipulate/transform them.

The "Writable" portion of Rx is called an `Observer` and is usually abstracted with either a `Subject`, a `Relay` or a manual creation using `Observable.create`.

You can read more about Subjects here: 
https://speakerdeck.com/freak4pc/rxswift-debunking-the-myth-of-hard?slide=34